# fancybox jquery full width

Tags: jquery, fancybox, width

I try to  display images in full width but my solution not work:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
   $("a[rel=example_group]").fancybox({
            'transitionIn': 'none',
            'transitionOut': 'none',
            'titlePosition': 'over',
            'width':'100%'
            'titleFormat': function(title, currentArray, currentIndex, currentOpts) {
                return '<span id="fancybox-title-over">Image ' + (currentIndex + 1) + ' / ' + currentArray.length + (title.length ? ' &nbsp; ' + title : '') + '</span>';
            }
        });
     </script>
```

How can I have a full width or height image?
Tnx

Comment: you are missing a comma after `width : "100%",`

Comment: you may need to set `autoScale` to `false` (fancybox v1.3.4)